# HTML: How can I make cut-out typography?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typography

I would like to have a low-z-index div displaying a movie (flash or HTML5, whatever), and a second high-z-index div that is white with some text that "cuts out the white" to see through to the movie.

In other words, as if you printed Hello in large font on a piece of paper, then took an Xacto-knife and meticulously cut out every part of Hello like a stencil and then pasted this paper on a TV screen. You would see the moving colors of the TV within the word Hello.

I'm interested in any way of doing this in a browser, and it doesn't necessarily have to be CSS-only or work with old IE. It just has to work with "modern" browsers like Webkit-anything.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a [mask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layers_%28digital_image_editing%29#Layer_Mask).

In "normal" HTML this isn't possible (or at least not readily possible). Traditional HTML doesn't do this this kind of digital imaging. In the past, you might have used Flash for stuff like this. Now, however, we have the `canvas` tag.

The basic idea is that you will have two HTML layers: (1) your movie; (2) a canvas tag. The canvas tag will cover the movie. On the canvas will be composed a white rectangle (obscuring the movie) and text (which will act as a mask against the white rectangle). The mask will "punch through" the white rectangle and you will see the movie playing behind.

Here's an example doing something similar to what you want:

- http://blog.ericzhang.com/punch-through-text-masks-with-css-and-html5/